# Logstash : FileNotFoundException when reading from MongoDB with JDBC driver

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I have the exact same error as described [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sync-data-from-mongodb-using-logstash/275918).
My objective is to read data from a Mongo collection to an Elastic index, using Logstash.

#### Installation

To do that, I've been using Docker to simulate the ELK stack and MongoDB database. Every service is in the same docker network `elastic`.

- No user has been added in MongoDB.
- Settings of Logstash are default.
- Version of ELK stack is `7.14.0`.

#### Drivers

- I downloaded JDBC Mongo drivers here : http://www.dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/MongoDbJdbcDriver.zip and unzipped the compressed file in `~/driver`

#### Pipeline config

Here is the pipeline config :

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/logstash/mongo_drivers/mongojdbc3.1.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://mongo01-test:27017/my-database"
    jdbc_user => ""
    schedule => "0 * * * *"
    statement => "db.items.find({});"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["es01-test:9200"]
    index => "items-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

#### Docker run command

```sh
docker run --name log01-test --net elastic -v ~/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ -v ~/driver/:/opt/logstash/mongo_drivers/ docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.14.0
```

#### Output logs

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:200: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-08-06T15:16:02,238][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties
[2021-08-06T15:16:02,250][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.14.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.19.0 (2.5.8) 2021-06-15 55810c552b OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9 on 11.0.11+9 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:02,273][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:02,289][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:02,777][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"0dc63ab4-c361-4822-922d-7d981780e3b3", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:03,832][WARN ][logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] xpack.monitoring.enabled has not been defined, but found elasticsearch configuration. Please explicitly set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: true` in logstash.yml
[2021-08-06T15:16:03,836][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
[2021-08-06T15:16:04,368][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2021-08-06T15:16:04,980][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2021-08-06T15:16:05,191][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:05,239][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Marking url as dead. Last error: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch {:url=>http://elasticsearch:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:05,248][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:05,302][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
[2021-08-06T15:16:05,696][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-08-06T15:16:06,615][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 96 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 120 keys and 417 values
[2021-08-06T15:16:07,771][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.inputs.jdbc] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2021-08-06T15:16:07,882][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,003][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//es01-test:9200"]}
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,030][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://es01-test:9200/]}}
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,082][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://es01-test:9200/"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,139][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (7.14.0) {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,143][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,298][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2021-08-06T15:16:08,408][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/test-logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3cff6ed run>"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:09,644][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.23}
[2021-08-06T15:16:09,713][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:09,789][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/logstash/.DbSchema/logs/MongoDbJdbcDriver.log.lck
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:182)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:511)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:307)
        at com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver.<clinit>(MongoJdbcDriver.java:37)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaSupportImpl.loadJavaClass(JavaSupportImpl.java:157)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyClassOrNull(Java.java:961)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyClassOrNull(Java.java:948)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyOrPackageUnderPackage(Java.java:905)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage.method_missing(JavaPackage.java:252)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$method_missing.call(JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$method_missing.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:833)
        at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers$MethodMissingMethod.call(Helpers.java:591)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:196)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callMethodMissing(CachingCallSite.java:440)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:352)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:144)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:345)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(Interpreter.java:106)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.evalCommon(Interpreter.java:158)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.evalWithBinding(Interpreter.java:182)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1086)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1048)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.gen)
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_45_dot_0.lib.sequel.adapters.jdbc.RUBY$method$load_driver$0(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.45.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:55)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_integration_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_1_dot_4.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.common.RUBY$method$load_driver$0(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.1.4/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/common.rb:27)
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_integration_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_1_dot_4.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.common.RUBY$method$load_driver$0$__VARARGS__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.1.4/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/common.rb)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_integration_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_1_dot_4.lib.logstash.inputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$run$0(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.1.4/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:292)
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_integration_minus_jdbc_minus_5_dot_1_dot_4.lib.logstash.inputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$run$0$__VARARGS__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.1.4/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)
        at usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$inputworker$0(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:405)
        at usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$inputworker$0$__VARARGS__(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)
        at usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$block$start_input$1(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:396)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)
        at org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)
        at org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)
        at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.9/lib/rufus/scheduler/cronline.rb:77: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
[2021-08-06T15:16:35,282][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2021-08-06T15:16:35,633][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
^C[2021-08-06T15:16:39,600][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGINT received. Shutting down.
[2021-08-06T15:16:39,623][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] SIGINT received. Terminating immediately..
[2021-08-06T15:16:39,646][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ]
org.jruby.exceptions.ThreadKill: null
```

- Then, I noticed that the directory `/usr/share/logstash/.DbSchema/` is never created. Do I need to configure Logstash settings to solve this issue ?

Any help will be really appreciated on this topics, many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Root cause

Comes from in the source code of MongoDbJdbcDriver class, at the static initializer [here](https://github.com/wise-coders/mongodb-jdbc-driver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dbschema/MongoJdbcDriver.java).

Here below the problematic 37th line :

```java
final FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.DbSchema/logs/MongoDbJdbcDriver.log");
```

It only works if directory `~/.DbSchema/logs` exists, which isn't the case when running logstash container.

### Solutions

- Use another MongoDB driver suitable for JDBC.
- Or create a docker image from the Logstash one with the following content :

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.14.0
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/logstash/.DbSchema/log
```